# apt tells me I have "held broken packages": please help me reinstall skype

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, dependencies

Ubuntu version: up to date 12.04

I recently uninstalled Skype so that I could reinstall the most recent version; I was getting the "packages held back" message whenever I updated the software on my system and stupidly thought this was a good idea.

The result is that now I cannot get skype reinstalled because of broken packages/dependencies. I have tried installing the version I had installed (4.1.0.20.0-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) without success:

```
# apt-get install skype=4.1.0.20.0-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
skype : Depends: skype-bin
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.


# apt-get install skype-bin=4.1.0.20.0-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
skype-bin:i386 : Depends: libqtwebkit4:i386 (>= 2.2~2011week36) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The strange thing is that I have libqtwebkit4 **version 2.2.1** installed:

```
# dpkg -s libqtwebkit4
(...)
Status: install ok installed
(...)
Version: 2.2.1-1ubuntu4
```

How can I fix this situation? As far as I can tell I have a sufficiently recent libqtwebkit4 package installed yet apt won't let me install skype-bin.

Running aptitude search skype, I get:

```
pi  skype 
p   skype:i386 
v   skype-bin  
pB  skype-bin:i386
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing I always try if I have problems with skype is to install a debian package from their [site](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/get-skype/on-your-computer/linux/downloading.ubuntu64). If I remember correctly, it doesn't have the `skype-bin` dependency, but rather comes as a bundle.

Regarding your `libqtwebkit4` problem, I think that you have the 64-bit version installed when skype requires the 32-bit version.

Comment: thank you for your reply! How can I install the i386 version of libqtwebkit4 for skype to be happy? When I try to install libqtwebkit4:i386 apt tells me that "The following packages have unmet dependencies: libqtwebkit4:i386 : Depends: libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-0:i386 (>= 0.10.31) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libsqlite3-0:i386 (>= 3.5.9) but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.".

Comment: Try installing the `ia32-libs` package and then running `apt-get` with the `-f` switch.

Comment: Trying to install ia32-libs produces: The following packages have unmet dependencies: ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.